# Static_Cast C++ how to change an INT variable to display CHAR

Tags: c++

I'm brand new to C++ and am trying to make a program that when the user inputs an int between 0-9 it displays the number, and between 9 and 36 displays the corresponding letter, A= 10 B= 11... I know how to use the switch function but with 26 cases that's a lot of typing. How would I use static_cast to convert the Int variables to Chars?

Comment: What made you jump to the conclusion that you need `static_cast`? What is the _real_ problem that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this will probably do what you want.

```
int num = 12;  //  Input number

char ch;
if (num < 10)
    ch = num + '0';
else
    ch = num + 'a' - 10;
```

or alternatively:

```
const char DIGITS[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

int num = 12;          //  Input number

char ch = DIGITS[num]; //  Output number/letter
```

So there's no need to cast anything.

If you want capital letters instead, replace the `'a'` with `'A'` in the first example. The second example is trivial to switch to capitals.

Comment: One should note that this requires your execution character set to contain all letters in a contiguous sequence. This is usually the case, but it *is* an assumption. An index into a static array would be a somewhat more portable solution.

Comment: I was in the middle of adding the array indexing idea when you mentioned that. Thanks!

Comment: @Mysticial but why the array is called DIGITS ;)? I would rather call that ALPHANUMS.

Comment: @doc It was chosen arbitrarily. I use `DIGITS` by habit since I've done some work with number representations in other bases. So if you want to print something out in base 62, you would use `const char DIGITS[] = 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't. Just output them. Streams already do lexical conversion for you.

```
int x = 64;
std::cout << x; // outputs "64"

char c = 'B';
std::cout << c; // outputs "B"
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
char IntToChar(int j)
{
    if( (j >= 0) && (j <= 9) ) return '0' + static_cast<char>(j);
    if( (j >= 10) && (j <= 36) ) return 'A' + static_cast<char>(j - 10);
    /* whatever you want here */
}
```

Comment: The static_cast<char> is wasted. Any arithmetic operation (such as '+') is done on int (int is smallest size for any predefined operator). So you convert j to a char then before the addition '0' is converted from char to int and then your cast value is converted from char (back) to int then the addition performed returning an int the result is the converted to char for the return. So the static_cast will only have an effect (and truncate the value) if j exceeds the size of a char which you guarantee will not happen because of your conditionals.

Comment: It's kind of a personal preference. Where casts are intentional and part of the program logic, I prefer to make them explicit.

Comment: Then maybe it would be better to cast '0' to int rather than j to a char. Personally I think the above makes the code harder to read and understand (in addition to not do anything useful). But that's my personal preference.

Comment: @LokiAstari: The point is to vouch to a reviewer for the safety of the cast. Basically, you're saying, "I have made sure `j` fits in the range of an `char`." That breaks the reviewers job into two simpler jobs, checking that your vouch is correct and then checking that the implicit cast from int->char is safe. In this simple case, it doesn't matter, but in more complex cases, it makes it easier for a reviewer to follow the programmer's logic. (It may not be clear at that point in the code that `j` isn't a `char` already, so the reviewer may not see the implicit cast.)

Comment: But there would never be an implicit cast on j. J is an integer. Before the operator '+' is applied '0' will be converted to an integer. The implicit conversion is for the character to be upcast to an integer.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Right, but those are details of the language/implementation. The programmer is trying to make clear the intention of the code, so that the intention of the code can be understood and validated independent of the implementation. (Essentially, he's coding as if C had a way to add characters, because that's the operation he really wants, and the fact that it internally uses integers doesn't affect his code's correctness or operation, so he is free to ignore it.) One important thing about writing understandable code is to make the intent clear. The intent is to add characters.